# Laravel Bootstrap error not working on my pc but working good on another

Tags: laravel-5, bootstrap-4

I am trying to develop a laravel site. I am trying to apply a template in the blade files. I have added the necessary folder to my public folder. This file is also working correctly in my friends pc but not on my pc. Can anyone help me with the problem?

I also copy paste my friends which works fine in his pc but not on my pc.

Comment: What error you are getting?. Please post more info about issue.

Comment: i am not getting any it is not showing any css just everything is working fine .. but in my another pc it is working with all the css

Comment: Then you have to check all ```settings``` ```paths``` for CSS files properly.

Comment: its the same folder just copy and paste full folder the paths are not changed 

it is not working on chrome and ie 

but one function preloader is just working on firefox

Comment: its just copy and paste all the things are same to same

Comment: What about rest of features? Apart from CSS is everything working?

Comment: @sh1515 open your browser web inspector and check the console for any errors or warnings there and let us know what you see there

Comment: Sounds like a browser issue.  What are you / your friend using (and versions).

Comment: Also.  Welcome to web development.  "It works on my machine..."

Comment: the versions are also same